# Stop video when modal is close - Plyr plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plyr

I created multiple video player in multiple modals with Plyr plugin. One video by modal.

https://github.com/sampotts/plyr

I'm trying to stop current video when the current modal is closed.

Can I have some help please ?

```
Plyr.setup('.popin__video-container');

    $('.btn-open').each(function(i, el) {
        var modal = $('#' + $(el).attr('data-modal'));
        var overlay = $('.popin__overlay');
        var close = $('.btn-action');

        function removeModal() {
            modal.removeClass('statut-show');
            overlay.removeClass('statut-show');
        }

        function removeModalHandler() {
            removeModal();
        }

        $(el).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            modal.addClass('statut-show');
            overlay.addClass('statut-show');
        });

        close.click(function(e) {
            if($(e.target).hasClass('btn-action')) {
                e.preventDefault();
                removeModalHandler();

                var playerPopin = modal.find('.plyr');

                if (!playerPopin.paused) {
                    playerPopin.pause();
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try assigning the initialized method for the player to a variable, then calling the `pause` method like so.

`let player = Plyr.setup('.popin__video-container');`

`player.pause();`

This is what the documentation says.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that too. I have an error message : Cannot read property 'pause' of null

Answer (score 1):

after setting up plyr. whenever you use the variable it gives you an array to handle.

so you should do sth like this:

```
            const players = Plyr.setup('.js-player');
            players.forEach(function(player) {
                        player.pause();
            });
```

or if you're working with bootstrap modals:

```
            const players = Plyr.setup('.js-player');
            $('.myModal').on('hide.bs.modal',function (){

                  players.forEach(function(player) {
                        player.pause();
                  });
            });
```

you can check this link too : https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/issues/144

Comment: Thank you for your contribution :-) I will test

Comment: I'm glad to help. ;)